# Laravel Livewire Turbolinks with Image lazyload

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, lazy-loading, laravel-livewire, turbolinks

I am trying to build a website on Laravel Livewire with Vanilla Lazyload and Turbolink. On refreshing the page, image on page is lazyloaded, but soon I click on link, image do not lazy load until I manually refresh or enter the page. Default low quality images is visible which are just placeholder.

Anyone could guide or share a link so I can lazyload images in Livewire Turbolink. ANy other suggestion to make application act like a SPA, also welcomes.

Thanks.

---

Edit

---

```js
//app.js
const Turbolink = require('turbolinks');
Turbolink.start();
window.LazyLoad = require('vanilla-lazyload');
```

```php
// card.blade.php
<a href="{{ $url }}" class="hover:text-black">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 bg-white rounded-lg hover:shadow-md border border-slate-100 py-4 hover:bg-slate-100 ease-in duration-300 cursor-pointer px-2">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/defaults/banner.jpg') }}" data-src="{{ $image }}" class="lazy w-52 mx-auto my-2">
        <div class="col-span-2">
            <p class="text-sm pt-3 font-inter m-auto">16 Jul, 2022</p>
            <h3 class="text-xl font-frank m-auto">{{ $title }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

When I refresh the page via F5 or manually enter address, this is how images are loaded which is what I want.

[on page refresh how I images are loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL0Lx.png)

This is how I end up on clicking any link which is processed by Turbolink.

[on clicking any link on page which is processed by Turbolink I end up with low quality images only. like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwdUE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, edited post with code and screenshot. I hope this is clear now to understand the issue. @SujithSandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got the answer after a lot of research.

in turbolinks, on clicking any URL you need to re-init your js on load, which can be done in JS as

```js
window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){...}
```

via jQuery

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:visit',function(){...}
```

This might be useful for someone, who visits this post. You actually need to listen to event and then re-init.

This is useful if you are using Turbolink 5 or newer version. For older version you need to listen for `page:load` instead of `turbolinks:visit`.